# How albumentations work with keras Sequence

Tags: keras, sequence, data-augmentation, albumentations

I have read [this](https://medium.com/the-artificial-impostor/custom-image-augmentation-with-keras-70595b01aeac) tutorial for using albumentations with keras sequence. The code is as follows :
`

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import Sequence

class CIFAR10Sequence(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size, augmentations):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.augment = augmentations

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        
        return np.stack([
            self.augment(image=x)["image"] for x in batch_x
        ], axis=0), np.array(batch_y)
```

`

The thing is I don't understand how it is augmenting ( i.e. providing more samples ) the data. The way I see it, it is just transforming the samples in the dataset, and not generating newer ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the tutorial you provided you may see that the author defines AUGMENTATIONS_TRAIN and AUGMENTATIONS_TEST objects which perform the actual augmentation.

Then these objects are passed to the sequence generator above:

```
train_gen = CIFAR10Sequence(x_train, y_train, hparams.train_batch_size, augmentations=AUGMENTATIONS_TRAIN)
```

so that calling `self.augment` actually augments every image in the batch:

```
self.augment(image=x)["image"] for x in batch_x
```

And yes, augmentation doesn't mean creating new objects but applying random transformation to existing ones to create 'artifical' objects which are somewhat different from the originals.

Comment: Thank you very much. This issue of mine was resolved a fewer days after I posted it but forgot to close it. Your answer may help others who search for Albumentations and I'm keeping the topic. However, my question was mostly directed at how we can actually increase our data and the answer is by just multiplying the image sources ( e.g. image path lists)